# Showing div when inputs have been filled

Tags: jquery

I want to show next div if all inputs have been filled inside first div

i've managed to make that work inside parent element

```
<fieldset>
    test fieldset 1
    <form>
        <div class="row active-q">
            test 1
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="row active-q">
          test 2
          <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="row active-q">
          test 3
          <input type="text">
      </div>
  </form>
  <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      test fieldset 2
      <form>
        <div class="row active-q">
          test 4
          <input type="text">
      </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>



//input check for filled / empty to display another one
$('input[type="text"],input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"], select').bind(
    "keyup change", function () {
        // get elements that are empty.
        var empty = $(
            'input[type="text"], input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"], select'
        ).map(function (index, el) {
            return !$(el).val().length ? el : null;
        }).get();

        // could also be placed outside of the function
        var number = $(this).closest(".active-q").next();

        // check if there are any empty elements, if there are none, show numbers, else hide number.
        !empty.length ? number.hide() : number.show().css("display", "flex");
    }
);
```

My question is, how do i show next fieldset if all active-q have been filled?
https://codepen.io/nikolamilovac/pen/Paqvvb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create two div with id (you can also set the id of field set and simply show hide on onchange function, here i am focusing on div ) and set display none of second div which you want to open after filling all the field-

```
  <div id="div1">
     <input type="text" id="text1" />
     <input type="text" id="text2" />
 </div> 

 <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" id="text3" />
    <input type="text" id="text4" />
</div>
```

then create simple change function on last textbox where you want to open new div, on change function if all field is fill then it will show the second div otherwise it will throw the message to fill the all field-

```
 $("#text2").change(function(){
    var one=$('#text1').val();
    var two=$('#text2').val();
      if(one!="" && two!="")
        {
          $('#div2').show();
          return true;
        }
     else
        {
          alert('Please fill all the field');
          return false;
        }
    });
```

hope it will help you.